# Create a Batch to delete a file using the name of another file

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder which contains only one file (file name and extension will be different every time the batch will run), I need to delete the file from another folder that have the same name as file from the first folder.

**Example:**

`Folder1` have only one file called: `123456.123`

Folder2 have lots of files including `123456.123`

Locations:
`c:\Test\Folder1\`

`c:\Test\Folder2\`

---

Any Help is Appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for %%a in ("c:\test\folder1\*") do del /q/f/a "c:\test\folder2\%%~nxa" 2>nul
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

```
:: Put path to mother folder below
cd "C:\test\"
:: Put Folder1's name below
pushd "Folder1"

for "delims=" /f %%a in ('dir /b *.*') do (set name=%%a)
popd
:: Put Folder2's Name below
pushd "Folder2"

:: Remove "Echo" from below line to delete the file
Echo del %name%
popd
```

And that will do what you want. Notice the `Echo` in front of `del %name%` will prevent it from actually deleting the files. This is only for testing it. If there are no problems, remove the `Echo and it will function fine.

Mona